# Ethereum HD Wallet implementation in Flutter, is there any library in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

**Are there any existing libraries in flutter to create Ethereum HD wallet?**

I have used ethereumjs-wallet npm package to generate a unique wallet address in node.js

```
var hdkey = require('ethereumjs-wallet/hdkey');
var extPubKey = 'xpub7njbhgvjhiuiUoTXAL56JpQYLq5FyXaZypJiKdsAbHKzMUQsSiJTNSMnBtYYRXxda9C6fUx6mMMqatUDNFSKxxXcpBckijohuWiQN8p5';
var hdwallet = hdkey.fromExtendedKey(extPubKey);
var wallet = hdwallet.getWallet();
var address = wallet.getAddress();
console.log(`Eth Address: 0x${address.toString('hex')}`);
```

> I want to use the above script in flutter but **ethereumjs-wallet** library is not available in flutter libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I have built a digital wallet in flutter using web3dart (https://pub.dev/packages/web3dart) library , checkout this https://github.com/allanclempe/ether-wallet-flutter
That is a simple implementation how to generate private and public key from mnemonic, get contract balance and transfer tokens.

Answer (score 2):

You can give the `ethereum 4.0.1` package a go, found [here](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/ethereum). It currently implements most of the Ethereum api's and some of the Admin api's.

Comment: there is no way to generate ethereum hd wallet using ethereum 4.0.1 package

Comment: @chitharu007 have you tried `web3dart 0.4.5`? If that doesn't work then I'm afraid there aren't any more packages that currently implement Ethereum HD wallets

Comment: tell me if you know any way to generate Ethereum address using mnemonic or privatekey in flutter

Answer (score 1):

you can use [BIP-32](https://pub.dev/packages/bip32) package from pub.dev to derive HD wallets that are compatible with bitcoin improvement proposal 32.

```
BIP32 node = BIP32.fromSeed(seed);
BIP32 child = node.derivePath("m/44'/0'/0'/0/0");
```

m/44'/0'/0'/0/0 is the path for the ethereum address. You can get the public and private key by calling the child BIP32 class.

```
child.publickey 
child.privatekey
```

privatekey would be in uint8list, you can hex encode it to get the private key as string. To convert the publickey to Ethereum address, you can use the followig code.

```
import "dart:convert";
import "dart:typed_data";

import "package:convert/convert.dart" show hex;
import 'package:pointycastle/digests/keccak.dart';

import "util.dart";

/// Derives an Ethereum address from a given public key.
String ethereumAddressFromPublicKey(Uint8List publicKey) {
  final decompressedPubKey = decompressPublicKey(publicKey);
  final hash = KeccakDigest(256).process(decompressedPubKey.sublist(1));
  final address = hash.sublist(12, 32);

  return checksumEthereumAddress(hex.encode(address));
}

/// Converts an Ethereum address to a checksummed address (EIP-55).
String checksumEthereumAddress(String address) {
  if (!isValidFormat(address)) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(address, "address", "invalid address");
  }

  final addr = strip0x(address).toLowerCase();
  final hash = ascii.encode(hex.encode(
    KeccakDigest(256).process(ascii.encode(addr)),
  ));

  var newAddr = "0x";

  for (var i = 0; i < addr.length; i++) {
    if (hash[i] >= 56) {
      newAddr += addr[i].toUpperCase();
    } else {
      newAddr += addr[i];
    }
  }

  return newAddr;
}

/// Returns whether a given Ethereum address is valid.
bool isValidEthereumAddress(String address) {
  if (!isValidFormat(address)) {
    return false;
  }

  final addr = strip0x(address);
  // if all lowercase or all uppercase, as in checksum is not present
  if (RegExp(r"^[0-9a-f]{40}$").hasMatch(addr) ||
      RegExp(r"^[0-9A-F]{40}$").hasMatch(addr)) {
    return true;
  }

  String checksumAddress;
  try {
    checksumAddress = checksumEthereumAddress(address);
  } catch (err) {


    return false;
      }

  return addr == checksumAddress.substring(2);
```

}

util.dart

```
import "dart:typed_data";

import "package:pointycastle/ecc/curves/secp256k1.dart";
import 'package:pointycastle/pointycastle.dart';

String strip0x(String address) {
  if (address.startsWith("0x") || address.startsWith("0X")) {
    return address.substring(2);
  }
  return address;
}

bool isValidFormat(String address) {
  return RegExp(r"^[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$").hasMatch(strip0x(address));
}

Uint8List decompressPublicKey(Uint8List publicKey) {
  final length = publicKey.length;
  final firstByte = publicKey[0];

  if ((length != 33 && length != 65) || firstByte < 2 || firstByte > 4) {
    throw ArgumentError.value(publicKey, "publicKey", "invalid public key");
  }

  final ECPoint? ecPublicKey = ECCurve_secp256k1().curve.decodePoint(publicKey);
  return ecPublicKey!.getEncoded(false);
}
```